# Can I retrieve filename for external table data in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

Looking to implement a simple datastore for a departmental team where they currently manage a load of excel/csv files. We will get them to prepare the files and drop them in CSV format into a GCS bucket and then point an external BQ table at this (that all works great).

However, if they run a query and see some data and then want to find where that data has actually been pulled from, how can we find out (assuming there is no contextual clues in the filename) which file contains the row(s) in question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the _FILE_NAME pseudo column to look at the file to which a row belongs for external tables. Note that the pseudo column only works for external tables. Example:

```
bq query --external_table_definition=externalTable::AVRO=gs://mybucket/f* 'SELECT _FILE_NAME as f FROM externalTable'
```

Comment: is there any chance for this type of info to be in documentation!?

Comment: Indeed. It was an unintended omission. We'll fix that shortly.

Comment: Brilliant. I'll delete my answer in that case.

Comment: Just an update -- this is now available in the official documentation.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/federated-data-sources#the_file_name_pseudo_column

Comment: Has this feature been removed? I can't see it on the docs and I get the following error `Invalid field name "_FILE_NAME". Field names are not allowed to start with the (case-insensitive) prefixes _PARTITION, _TABLE_, _FILE_ and _ROW_TIMESTAMP`

Comment: @DanielWorthington-Bodart you need to specify a column alias in order to use it. Eg: "SELECT _FILE_NAME as fileName FROM ..."

Answer (score 2):

you don't need the function - just the alias, as column names cannot start with an underscore

```
select _FILE_NAME f from externalTable
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding a function before, like say `lower()` gives the output instead of error "Invalid field name "_FILE_NAME"

try this :

```
SELECT lower(_FILE_NAME) as f FROM externalTable'
```