# How to include DeltaLake Files from GCS to BigQuery

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, delta-lake

Is there a library/connector available to import [Delta Lake](https://delta.io/) files stored in Google Cloud Storage (GCS) directly to BigQuery?

I have managed to write BigQuery tables using a Spark Dataframe as intermediary but I can't find any direct connector or BigQuery Library that does this without transitioning through Spark dataframes.

I tried using the official connector [spark-bigquery-connector](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/spark-bigquery-connector), but documentation is lacking on how to point to a specific project in BigQuery so I couldn't go further than loading the DeltaLake files from GCS in a Dataframe.

Using Javier's comment, I managed to write to BQ, but this solution isn't optimized and as much as I can optimize the Spark Job, it won't be as direct as using a Google Bigquery library that does it under the hood

Not finding any direct solution, I ended up using spark-bigquery-connector to ingest Delta files as follows:

```
myDeltaTable.toDF
  .write
  .format("bigquery")
  .mode("overwrite")
  .option("parentProject", "MY_PARENT_PROJECT")
  .option("project", "MY_PROJECT")
  .option("temporaryGcsBucket", "A_STAGING_BUCKET_IN_GCS") // Mandatory
  .option("partitionField", "MY_PARTITION_FIELD")
  .save("DATASET.TABLE")
```

Comment: Could you share what have you done so far to load DeltaLike files into a Dataframe? A code snippet and details would be great to have a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also, according to the [documentation](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/spark-bigquery-connector#:~:text=Read%2FWrite-,project,-The%20Google%20Cloud), you can set a project ID using the property `project` as such: `.option("project", "[PROJECT-ID]")`. But I don't know if you've already tried it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to ingest a Datalake file in GCS to BigQuery without going through some intermediary.

You could setup a GCE VM that downloads the Datalake file from GCS, reads it using the [Datalake Standalone Connector](https://github.com/delta-io/connectors/wiki/Delta-Standalone-Reader) and then write to BigQuery (either by the streaming API or writing to a supported format like Parquet and importing).

However this is essentially doing manually the same thing that Spark would be doing.

Comment: Hello David and thanks for the answer.
We are considering other options as this architecture might not be the most optimized one. We're ingesting raw data to GCS, processing it through Spark then reingesting the result tables in both GCS and BigQuery. it seems like with Delta and without an "under the hood" solution to ingest delta format to BQ, it's an overkill to keep the tables in both GCS and BQ

Comment: Yes, unfortunately if you want to use BigQuery you will either need to duplicate the data in a format BigQuery supports, ingest a copy of it to BigQuery, or move from DataLake format to one BigQuery supports.

Answer (score 3):

Recently Google announced the support for Delta Lake on BigTable, not sure how that will go with BigQuery.

See:

- https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/google-cloud-next/whats-next-for-digital-transformation-in-the-cloud
- https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/google-cloud-next/google-cloud-next22-wrap-up
- https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/building-most-open-data-cloud-all-data-all-source-any-platform

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve some of what you´re looking for:

1. creating external tables that point both to `_delta_log` json file folder and to the actual parquet data; and
2. creating view that queries only the files that was added and not removed from `_delta_log`.

Neil brings up a very good content [on his medium post](https://medium.com/google-cloud/delta-tables-with-dataproc-jupyter-and-bigquery-ea2509ca9e0f) about the theme. Good stuff, you should have a look.

I did that and it worked. But I'm currently trying to overcome dynamic file prunning issue on BigQuery. For what I can see, BQ doesnt do this, even if I explicitly filters [`_FILE_NAME` pseudo-column](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38857421/2817904).